# How to access other PHP pages after login?

Tags: login-control

I am working on Customer Management System in PHP. After successful login, if user want to change password, he clicks on change password link. But when that page open there is problem that logging user disappear.

**How can i add user remembering code in every page of secure CMS?**

thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think is to add a cookie for a user id and a 64bit auth session key that pulls from a script upon login and gets set into the global scope.  Then the next `landing` page has a script to pull the user data as long as the auth key gets verified.  (this should prevent someone from duping the system that its not actually an administrator or some other user)